# set background color with div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with specific background color and the data within my page has the same background color. I want to show the same color to the entire page. Please find the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/48/.
The red color is seen only till data appears, if i add extra table we can see the background red color, i want to show the entire page with the same red color irrespective of the data is present or not.Please suggest. I should not give bgcolor to the body tag. What modification should i do to the existing css in order to show the red color to the entire page even if data is not available.

Sample code:

```
<div class="myDiv">  

<br/><br><br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="myData">Data1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="myData">Data2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="myData">Data3</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
    <table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="myData">Data1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="myData">Data2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="myData">Data3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS code:

```
.myDiv{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}
```

--EDIT--
I should not use body bgcolor as mentioned. With existing CSS code of myDiv i want to display the red color 90% of my entire page. Thanks.

Comment: with js document.bgColor='red';

Comment: I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610634/set-background-color-with-div/27610688#27610688) to give a possible solution to your edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surround your code in a `<body>` tag and use css on that body tag to have a `background:red`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/49/) is a jsfiddle.

From the link:

```
<body>
//your html
</body>
```

And the css would be

```
body {
    background:red;
}
```

Update:

Adjusting to your update, you can accomplish the background of the div being 90% red by surrounding `myDiv` with a body tag, and setting the height of that body tag to 100% and then setting the height of `myDiv` to 90%.

The new CSS would look something like this:

```
.myDiv{
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    background:red;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/52/)

Comment: You beat me by a minute, well played.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your css?

```
   body{
    background-color:red;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/51/)

Add this code to your javascript:

Vanilla javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")[0].style.height = Math.max(window.innerHeight, document.body.offsetHeight) + "px";
```

jQuery:

```
$(".myDiv").css({height: Math.max(window.innerHeight, document.body.offsetHeight)});
```

Comment: It's been posted twice!

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions and comments, but as i mentioned in the post, i should not use body bgcolor, as i have to use this css code for my project requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
div.myDiv{
    background-color: red;
}
```

I had a trouble like this with another property of divs, and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should define body width and height as 100%.
So try following:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.myDiv{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: With the code above, the red color is displayed only till the data exists, but i want to display 90% of my page even if data doesn't exist.

Comment: I tested the code in 3 different browsers and it works. Are you working inside jsfiddle?